# Streaming data into complex Json in PostgreSql

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have the following Json stored in the Jsonb column of PostgreSql. I have a requirement where I should be able to update the Json as and when the streaming of data occurs.

```
{
"root": [

    [{
            "cid": "CID1",
            "Display": "User One",
            "FName": "User",
            "LName": "One"
        }, {
            "cid": "CID1",
            "Display": "User Two",
            "FName": "User",
            "LName": "Two"
        }, {
            "cid": "CID1",
            "Display": "User Three",
            "FName": "User",
            "LName": "Three"
        }, {
            "cid": "CID2",
            "Display": "User One",
            "FName": "User",
            "LName": "One"
        }, {
            "cid": "CID2",
            "Display": "User Two",
            "FName": "User",
            "LName": "Two"
        }, {
            "cid": "CID2",
            "Display": "User Three",
            "FName": "User",
            "LName": "Three"
        }

    ],

    [{
        "cid": "CID1",
        "Display": "User One CID1",
        "FName": "Userfff",
        "LName": "One"
    }, {
        "cid": "CID1",
        "Display": "User Two CID1",
        "FName": "User",
        "LName": "Two"
    }, {
        "cid": "CID1",
        "Display": "User Three CID1",
        "FName": "User",
        "LName": "Three"
    }, {
        "cid": "CID1",
        "Display": "User four CID1",
        "FName": "Userfff",
        "LName": "four"
    }, {
        "cid": "CID1",
        "Display": "User five CID1",
        "FName": "User",
        "LName": "five"
    }, {
        "cid": "CID1",
        "Display": "User six CID1",
        "FName": "User",
        "LName": "six"
    }, {
        "cid": "CID2",
        "Display": "User One CID2",
        "FName": "User",
        "LName": "One"
    }, {
        "cid": "CID2",
        "Display": "User Two CID2",
        "FName": "User",
        "LName": "Two"
    }, {
        "cid": "CID2",
        "Display": "User Three CID2",
        "FName": "User",
        "LName": "Three"
    }, {
        "cid": "CID3",
        "Display": "User One CID3",
        "FName": "f",
        "LName": "One"
    }, {
        "cid": "CID3",
        "Display": "User Two CID3",
        "FName": "e",
        "LName": "Two"
    }, {
        "cid": "CID3",
        "Display": "User Three CID3",
        "FName": "d",
        "LName": "Three"
    }, {
        "cid": "CID3",
        "Display": "User four CID3",
        "FName": "c",
        "LName": "four"
    }, {
        "cid": "CID3",
        "Display": "User five CID3",
        "FName": "b",
        "LName": "five"
    }, {
        "cid": "CID3",
        "Display": "User six CID3",
        "FName": "a",
        "LName": "six"
    }, {
        "cid": "CID4",
        "Display": "User One CID4",
        "FName": "User",
        "LName": "One"
    }, {
        "cid": "CID4",
        "Display": "User Two CID4",
        "FName": "User",
        "LName": "Two"
    }, {
        "cid": "CID4",
        "Display": "User Three CID4",
        "FName": "User",
        "LName": "Three"
    }]

]
}
```

At a time, I should be able to insert a batch of records into this JSON, either in the root's first array or the second array. What should be the query to insert rows in this case (say, in root's first array), if this is possible?

Comment: take alook at http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/102906/adding-elements-into-postgresql-json-array-field

Comment: Example: `with t(j) as (select '{"root":[ [{"a":1}], [{"b":2}] ]}'::jsonb) select *, jsonb_set(j, '{root,0}', j->'root'->0 || '{"c":3}') from t;`

Comment: You are suffering from EBD - Extremely bad design.

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto, I agree it may have been a bad design but I am going through a phase where I have to freeze some design before I jump onto implementation. This is one of the few designs that are under observation, not chosen for the implementation.